# php - string concatenation gives strange result

Tags: php, concatenation

I have built an OpenCart module and tested it on a few shops and it works well. One client just reported to me a problem and after inspecting the html I saw this:

My code in the .tpl template file:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" > 
 <tbody> 
   <?php foreach($row['strings'] as $row_string){   

     $key = $row_string['key']; 
     $id = $row['simpleFilePathEscaped'].$key;  ?>

     <tr>      

       <td class="text-center"> 
         <label><?php echo $key; ?> </label> 
       </td> 

       <td class="text-center">
         <div>
           <input  id="text_value_<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_string['value']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $key; ?>" class="form-control" />
         </div>
       </td> 

       <td class="text-center" >
         <button  id="save_icon_<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="addLiteralToFile('<?php echo $row['secondary_file_path_escaped'] ?>', '<?php echo $key; ?>', '<?php echo $id;?>');" class="btn btn-primary"><i id="save_inner_icon_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
         <div id="loading_icon_<?php echo $id; ?>" <div  class="loader"></div> </div>  
       </td> 

     </tr>  
   <?php } ?> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The result for an example row in this client's shop is this:

```
<tr>                     
    <td class="text-center" > 
     <label>direction</label> 
    </td> 

    <td class="text-center">
     <div>
       <input id="text_value_" type="text" value="ltr" placeholder="direction" class="form-control">
     </div>
    </td> 

    <td class="text-center">
     <button id="save_icon_" onclick="addLiteralToFile('----home----admin----domains----itrend.si----public_html----test----admin----language----english----en-gb.php', 'direction', '');" class="btn btn-primary"><i id="save_inner_icon_" class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
     <div id="loading_icon_" <div="" class="loader"></div>   
    </td> 

</tr>
```

If you notice you will see that all instances of `<?php echo $id; ?>` give an empty string. so `id="save_icon_<?php echo $id; ?>"` becomes `id="save_icon_"`

That is extremely strange because `$id` is a concat of `$row['simpleFilePathEscaped']` and `$key`. Even if `$row['simpleFilePathEscaped']` is empty I know for sure that `$key` has a value...Because it is echoed and in this example it is "direction" (in the label tag)

Need some help finding out why this is happening...

```
$row = {  "strings" => array of  {  "key"=> string,  "value"=> string }, 
          "simpleFilePathEscaped" => string, 
          "secondary_file_path_escaped" => string, 
          "primary_file_path"=> string 
}
```

Comment: So what does `$row` look like?

Comment: do `var_dump($id);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly row{
"strings" => array of {"key"=>someKey, "value"=>someValue},
"simpleFilePathEscaped" => string,
secondary_file_path_escaped=> string,
"primary_file_path"=> string
}

Comment: @Leo Tahk I don't have access to the client's site to make code changes on the fly to debug this way. Every change I do has to be uploaded to the store and the client has to update which makes it slow and annoying for the client.

Comment: Nobody can read that, please put it in your questions and format it

Comment: the code you posted works fine if you have $row['simpleFilePathEscaped'], 
$row['strings'], $row['secondary_file_path_escaped']  with the right values..  you need to be sure whats in them

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're right I updated the question

Comment: ok probably wrong foreach, try changing it to ... foreach($strings as $key=>$value) ['key'] is $value then..

Comment: @Leo Tahk the same code works perfectly in my demo shop and a few others. That's what's making this weird

Comment: i see $row['strings'] not working right.. giving an empty value

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i misunderstood the way your $row is build.

if you make an example like

```
$row['strings'] = ['key' => 10];
$row['strings'] = ['key' => 110];

foreach($row['strings'] as $row_string)
$key = $row_string['key'];

print_r($key); //will give you an empty value
```

but `print_r($row);` // will give Array ( [strings] => Array ( ['key'] => 110 ) )`

you need to change your foreach.

```
foreach($row['strings'] as $row_key => $row_string)
$key = $row_key;
```

then it will give the 'key' on echo.

or you can do

```
foreach($row['strings'] as $row_string)
$key = key($row_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your code:

Given your array looks like this (as written in your question):

```
$row = [  "strings" => array of  {  "key"=> string,  "value"=> string }, 
          "simpleFilePathEscaped" => string, 
          "secondary_file_path_escaped" => string, 
          "primary_file_path"=> string 
]
```

It is not possible for this code:

```
<?php foreach($row['strings'] as $row_string){   

 $key = $row_string['key']; // <--- THIS is not possible with the array structure you presented
 $id = $row['simpleFilePathEscaped'].$key;  ?>

 <tr>      

   <td class="text-center"> 
     <label><?php echo $key; ?> </label> 
   </td>
```

to print this as you suggested in your question:

```
<tr>                     
<td class="text-center" > 
 <label>direction</label> 
</td>
```

Because during the foreach loop, the `$row_string` variable will hold a string value but you are trying to access it as an array with an associative key.